# AWS mod_wsgi error when deploying Flask with elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Getting the following error with flask on elasticbeanstalk:

```
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3: can't open file 'mod_wsgi': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994357 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363] mod_wsgi (pid=7748): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994407 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363] mod_wsgi (pid=7748): SystemExit exception raised by WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' ignored.
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994449 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994511 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 3, in <module>
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994518 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]     app.run(debug=True)
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994553 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994560 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994590 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 623, in run_simple
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994596 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]     reloader_type)
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994624 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 231, in run_with_reloader
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994630 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363]     sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
[Sat Aug 08 23:43:35.994652 2015] [:error] [pid 7748] [remote 127.0.0.1:45363] SystemExit: 2
```

I'm using elasticbeanstalk command line interface to deploy the flask app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `app.run` in production.  Don't use the dev server in production.

`mod_wsgi`, like any WSGI app server, expects to find an `application` instance when importing, but you're running the dev server instead.

Guard against running the dev server on import.  Depending on your `mod_wsgi` settings, it may expect the name `application` instead of `app` as well.

```
application = app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```